# Was Kazuki Takahashi involved in the modifications made in Yu-Gi-Oh! for reasons of censorship?

Tags: yu-gi-oh, censorship

Checking some [Youtube videos about censorship in Yu-Gi-Oh!](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=yugioh%20censorship) *(especcially [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6g6c_FxVTI))*, it seems that the motives for censorship are based mainly on:

- Sexual content/innuendoes
- Violence
- Religion references
- And others (offensive language, stereotypes, [political matters](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Artworks:Psychic_Commander), etc.)

There is a [entire list of modified cards](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_modified_card_artworks), but I'm looking for Kazuki Takahashi's words about this subject that covers censorship in his anime, manga and cards<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> The linked sources shows the reasons for censorship *(i.e changes made in scenes and artwork card modifcations)*, but none of them mentions Kazuki Takahashi's opinion.

Comment: Meta discussion [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/2740/20729) and similar _but I hope no duplicate question_ [here](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/29534/20729).

Comment: Usually a question is only a duplicate of another question if the other question's answers also answer it. So there's no duplicate here, because your other question asked just about Pokemon. An answer about Pokemon wouldn't also answer this question about Yugioh.

Comment: It's just a same question but for a _different_ topic by the same OP.

Comment: I don't remember the source, hence the comment. Kazuki Takahashi has refused to censor several cards, one most commonly mentioned being the dark magician girl.

Comment: `MykAgustin` and `Torisuda`: I understand now, thank you for explain.
`Dimitri mx` thanks for your comment.